# Changing `Deleted Recent Questions` to `All Deleted Questions`

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, deleted-questions

Sometimes I lose a link to a deleted question and find it it my profile. It seems more helpful to have a complete list of deleted questions. But only recet deleted question links are available.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: that seems to be a different question I'm asking about deleted questions section and not normal section containing all undeleted nquestions.

Comment: No it's not different. You ask for a way to see all your deleted questions, the location is really not relevant. Don't get me wrong, I support such request and upvoted the original request (and downvoted Jeff answer) but I also try to keep the place organized.

Comment: yes in fact a way to access all deleted question. but it is partially available and I'm complaining about the word `recent`. why only recent why not all.

Comment: It's discussed in the linked dupe why not, the "recent" was added as kind of compromise to let users fix recent bad questions/answer they had.